# Row by row subtraction

Tags: sql

I have two views which contains the following data:

View lowbound

```
6
13
19
```

View upbound

```
3
9
14
```

I want to generate this result using two above views

```
3
4
5
```

which is 6 - 3 = 3, 13 -9 =4 and 19-14 =15.

I tried

```
 Select l.val - u.val from lowbound l, upbound u;
```

but here is its result

```
3
10
16
-3
4
10
-8
-1
5
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you tell which row in the first table goes witch which row in the other?

Comment: You mentioned views. Could these views be from a common table? If it does, use the parent table and you can subtract the values directly, without a join.

Answer (score 2):

So looks like you need to join the lowest number in view1 with the lowest in view2 and so on. If your DBMS supports `ROW_NUMBER` you can use something like

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT V1.val,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS RN
         FROM   View1 V1),
     T2
     AS (SELECT V2.val,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS RN
         FROM   View2 V2)
SELECT T1.val - T2.val
FROM   T1
       JOIN T2
         ON T1.RN = T2.RN
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebf86/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need a stored procedure then i'm using MSSQL server

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE lcursor CURSOR
 FOR SELECT * FROM l;
 DECLARE ucursor CURSOR
 FOR SELECT * FROM u;
 DECLARE @l INT;
 DECLARE @u INT;

 FETCH NEXT FROM lcursor 
 INTO @l
 FETCH NEXT FROM ucursor 
 INTO @u

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
      PRINT @l - @u
      FETCH NEXT FROM lcursor 
      INTO @l
      FETCH NEXT FROM ucursor 
      INTO @u
END
CLOSE lcursor 
DEALLOCATE lcursor 
CLOSE ucursor 
DEALLOCATE ucursor 
END
```

Comment: There is no `id` column specified.